# REST-like Apache VFS Implementation for FTP

Tags: mysql, apache, rest, ftp, vfs

I am very new to using Apache VFS. Is there a good example or documentation about writing a new VFS provider?

My use case is that I have metadata about files in a MySQL database, with the actual files stored in an object storage system. My goal to to build a virtual directory tree based on the metadata in the database, and upon download stream (and process on-the-fly) the files directly from the object store.

The framework in which I intend to use the VFS is an Apache Mina FTP server with the VFS Utils FTP Bridge as File System. If I understand it correctly all that is missing now is the proper VFS provider to build the virtual directory structure and connect to the file (this is intended for downloads only).

I (think I) understand the basic structure of VFS, but at this point I don't really know which components I have to implement to get it to work; or even where to start.